# Does chrome still use SSL after certificate warning?

Tags: certificates

We use a third party service which if I put its URL in the browser   , it display :

[image]

Looking at the certificate itself :

[image]

**Questions:**

1 - If I click "*Proceed to x...*" - Is the channel  still using SSL to transfer the data  ?

2- Am I safe to a middleman attack ?

3 - What other (if any) attacks am I exposed to ? ( except identity verification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason

> This certificate cannot be verified up to a trusted certification
>   authority

means that the issuer of the certificate is not known to Chrome. It may be a legit certificate (eg. signed by the server owner itself, or by an organization for internal use), or it might be a malicious middleman.
It might help to ask Chrome for more details and post that here - another possibilty is a real CA that fell out of favor recently. There are some cases where browsver vendors stopped to ship a certificate of a certain CA because they messed up in some way (eg. giving out certificates without any check that the applicant is a real person and owns the server)

> If I click "Proceed to x..." - Is the channel still using SSL to
>   transfer the data

Yes - your connection to the other side is still encrypted. The problem is, what is "the other side". You have no guarantee by some publicly known CA that it is really the server you want.

> Am I safe to a middleman attack ?

No.

> What other (if any) attacks am I exposed to ? ( except identity
>   verification)

As the server might not be the one you expect, everything you send there (or receive from there) might be not legit. It might be a "copy" of your bank site, and the attacker gets your code if you enter it. And so on...

Comment: Why am i not safe to mma? He can't read the data as he doesn't know the keys

Comment: @RoyiNamir Because it's possible that the certificate you got was made by the attacker (and then he knows the keys).